# Using cypress to test in bitbucket pipeline, testing an app running with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a web app with a separated frontend and backend, using traefik to handle the incoming connections.

I also have cypress set up as a separate docker compose service to use for E2E testing.

I have the traefik service set up with

```
extra_hosts:
  - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

I have the cypress service set up with

```
network_mode: "service:traefik"
```

I have a bash script that makes cypress run in docker compose.  Locally, this works flawlessly.  But in the bitbucket pipelines, I get an error:

```
1) Customer Page
   "before each" hook for "test known customer render":
 CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
http://host.docker.internal:8080/
The response we received from your web server was:
```

> 404: Not Found

I have tried just about everything I can find in the official documentations as well as Stack Overflow but I just can't find a way past this hurdle.  My Bitbucket pipeline sets up the environment, does a `docker compose up -d`, then runs `docker compose --profile cypress run cypress yarn test --config video=false $@`.

Any ideas on what is causing this issue?  8080 is the correct port. I do not believe the issue is Cypress, as doing `curl localhost:8080` gives a 400 error in the pipeline.  Something is causing the networking in docker compose to not behave the way I expect it to.

**Update**
After digging more, it seems the issue is with Traefik and Bitbucket. Traefik needs access to docker.sock, which Bitbucket seems to deny for security reasons.

Comment: call 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I believe I've tried that but I'll try it again.  curling localhost gives 404. Also, Cypress is attempting to connect to host.docker.internal:8080, not localhost.